# .bat file for copying folder to folder leaving out certain folders

Tags: batch-file, copy-paste, xcopy

Hi I need help to copy folders from one folder to another.

Suppose there are five folders named

```
forward1
forward2
forward3
Backward
Forward directions
```

and i need to copy only `forward1`,`forward2`,`forward3` into `Forward directions` leaving out `Backward` repetitively.

Is there any way to do this with batch files?

Comment: If you attempted to create the file, please include here what have you tried as well (even if it's not working). This will help us to help you better.

Comment: Should forward folders be created inside `Forward directions` or only the content of the source folders need to be copied?

Answer (score 0):

`Robocopy` has an exclude feature and has similar functions to `xcopy`

Comment: @Stonz2 Read **Answer the question** at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative." - While you may have provided a suggestion of a tool/command that could help, no effort was shown to actually answer how to achieve the desired result or how to use the suggested tool/command. Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it will help countless others.

Comment: @Stonz2 Your first reply to my answer was incorrect and unwelcome.  My answer supplies the information about a tool that solves the issue.  DO be more careful in what you copy and paste when you **think** the answer is not applicable.

Comment: On that point you are correct. I apologize and have removed the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for. This copies every file of the specified folders into the "*Forward directions*" folder.

*Be carefull with spaces in path-names.*

```
@echo off
set sources=forward1 forward2 forward3 forward4
set "destination=Forward directions"

for %%a in (%sources%) do (
    copy "%%a" "%destination%"
)
```

If you want to copy the folders, this would copy your folders into the "*Forward directions*" folder using `xcopy`.

```
@echo off
set sources=forward1 forward2 forward3 forward4
set "destination=Forward directions"

for %%a in (%sources%) do (
    xcopy "%%a" "%destination%/%%a" /IE
)
```

If you want to always overwrite directories/files, change `/IE` to `/IEY`.

Here is a full list of other usefull [Xcopy Options](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html).

Answer (score 0):

Either you try to copy the folder by creating the exclude list and the other way is to copy by providing the command like

```
%xcopy% %source%\forward1 %destination%\forward1
%xcopy% %source%\forward2 %destination%\forward2
%xcopy% %source%\forward3 %destination%\forward3
```